# Why some video posts from the same blog appear in google with thumbs, while others do not?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, video, video-sitemap

We own media blog - which is basically a big collection of various videos streamed through our branded player. Interesting thing is that some of our posts show up in google search results with a thumb denoting that the post in question is in fact a video. But more often they are not. We basically wonder why? What does affect it and can we control it somehow?

All posts (their single pages) have facebook og meta tags in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a video xml sitemap and tell Google what thumbnail to use for each video. It's possible they are gathering meta information from the videos and recognize them.

Comment: And how does one create such video xml sitemap? Is it any different from usual sitemap?

Comment: Depends, is your website static or on a CMS. And if on a CMS why not google CMS + video sitemap plugin/module/addon. Yes they are different than a normal XML sitemap